# using "case" in bash works on stings but not on numbers why?

Tags: bash, case

I have this code it should output "one" but it returns "zero" why?

```bash
function fourTeams () { 
  strings=($*)
  modulo=$(( strings[2] % 4 ))
  case $modulo in
    1) echo "one";;
    0) echo "zero";;
  esac
}

echo $(fourTeams $1 $2 1)
# output: "zero"
```

Comment: -1 for posting even though you saw that the result looks shitty in the preview.

Comment: What's in `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: files for another function.. but why does it matter?

Comment: It matters because if `$1` and/or `$2` are empty then `strings[2]` will be empty and `zero` is expected (which is likely the case).

Comment: aha thats right... thnx

Comment: Other problem if either argument has spaces in it, it will offset things in your array. Use `"$1"`, and use `$(...)` instead of backticks to prevent quoting madness.

Comment: To preserve spaces and quotes in filenames `$1` and `$1` use `"$@"` instead of `$*`. So you'd have `strings=($"@")`

Answer (score 2):

This outputs one like you expect:

```
function fourTeams { 
  strings=($@)
  modulo=$(( strings[2] % 4 ))
  case $modulo in
    1) echo "one" ;;
    0) echo "zero" ;;
  esac
}

main()
{
    local IFS=$'\n'
    echo $(fourTeams $1 $2 1)
}

main "my file one" "my file two"
```

Comment: `main "my file one" "my file two"` won't work. Use `"$@"` instead of `$*`.

Comment: @user3088572: without quotes both $@ and $* are same.

Comment: @random_thoughts - But with quotes they differ. Consider my sample input. `"$*"` will expand to `"my"` `"file"` `"one"` `"my"` `"file"` `"two"` whereas `"$@"` will expand to `"my file one"` `"my file two"`. Try it by running `fourTeams "my file one" "my file two" 1`

Comment: Updated based on comments.